# How to make a window in qt be the main focus

Tags: qt, qt5

So basically i have a class that inherits from `QMainWindow` and there's a toolbar action in my mainwindow that calls another small window where the user puts in some info, i want the mainwindow inaccessible i.e you shouldn't be able to click on it or interact with it unless you finish what you're doing on that small window or you close the small window. `setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);` only makes the small window be on top, but i can still access the MainWindow.

Comment: It sounds like you want a modal window. See the `modality` property of [QWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#modality-prop).

Comment: @JarMan thanks that did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all i needed was the `setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);` method